# How do I use a Trigger to synchronize ListBox selections?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have two list boxes which are bound to same observable collection. Basically one list box is a document tray where I drag & drop documents and other is a regular list box where I give the option to edit the file name. I want to highlight the items in both the listboxes. For example when the user selects a document in one listbox (tray) I want the list item with textbox in the other to be highlighted and likewise when I click on the text box in the other list box I want the item in the tray to be selected. I have my code as below.

In the Document Tray list box I have code as below.

```
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
  <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
      <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
  </Style>
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Similarly in the other list box I have the style like this

```
 <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin"  Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="True"></Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

When I select an item in the document tray the item is getting selected in the other list box. When I click on the text box or select an item in other list box the item is not getting selected in the tray list box. Also I noticed if I comment the focus trigger the items are getting selected appropriately. I want the selection to be propagated on focus also.

Comment: Lacking a complete code example, it is difficult to understand exactly what you're doing here. Is there a `DataTemplate` involved? Do your data items (i.e. in the `ObservableCollection`) have themselves an `IsSelected` property? If not, what is the context for the `IsProperty` setter bindings? Do a non-tray `ListBox` item get selected when the item has the keyboard focus? I.e. is it just a matter of propagation? Or does having the trigger prevent even that item from being selected? Does it fail to propagate only on focus changes, or does simply clicking the item also fail to propagate?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are binding your ListBox to data in code-behind (view model or otherwise) via a property, e.g. `YourItems`:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding YourItems}">
  <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
  ...
  </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

Create another property of the type that's within the collection in your code-behind, also (e.g. called `YourSelectedItem`.  Then just add the following line inside BOTH of your Listbox definitions:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding YourItems}" 
   SelectedItem="{Binding YourSelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}">
```

As long as both are bound two-way, then they should stay in-sync with each other.

I would not use setters in the style to set IsSelected (discard the lines `<Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />`).  The ListBoxes themselves have properties to handle that if you can bind to a common item in code-behind as shown above.  I'd need to try it, but then hopefully your trigger would work also since you won't have competing `IsSelected` triggers/styling.

I think the key thing here is that I've found that sometimes you cannot set something via trigger IF you've also set the same property via a style, so use `SelectedItem` on the ListBox parents, instead of an `IsSelected` style on each item.